# Trazer registros repetidos de 3 colunas na mesma tabela

Tags: php, mysql, select, group-by, distinct

Tenho uma tabela com dados de vale transporte dos meus funcionários da empresa:

```
nome ! valor1 ! valor2 ! valor3

teste1 ! 6.50 ! 0.00 ! 0.00
teste2 ! 4.30 ! 2.80 ! 1.10
teste3 ! 8.40 ! 1.10 ! 0.00
teste4 ! 2.85 ! 1.10 ! 0.00
```

onde é possível o funcionário pegar até 3 linhas de ônibus para vir ao trabalho, por isso tenho estas três colunas.

O problema que estou passando é o seguinte, quero retornar os dados das três colunas sem repetição, onde eu tenha todos valores de linhas de ônibus dos funcionários.

Preciso que me retorne se possível em uma única coluna os dados sem repetir, sem valores '0.00' e ordenado ascendente :

resultado

```
1.10
2.80
2.85
4.30 
6.50 
8.40
```

Comment: Você pode fazer 3 selects e usar o `union`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UNION`: para unir as 3 queries.

`GROUP BY`: para unir os resultados iguais.

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT valor1 valor FROM TABELA
UNION
SELECT valor2 valor FROM TABELA
UNION
SELECT valor3 valor FROM TABELA) TABELAX
WHERE valor > 0
GROUP BY valor
ORDER BY valor
```

`TABELAX`: alias.

Caso as colunas valor1, valor2 e valor3 tivessem somente um valor e os outros 0.00, você poderia usar o `CASE`, fazendo tudo em uma só query.

Também criar um `VIEW` desse select se caso utilizar sempre.

Comment: Certo, muito obrigado jovemm !! Deu bom demais .... abraxx

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer uma consulta por coluna, juntar tudo em uma consulta `UNION`, ordenando e agrupando o resultado:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT valor1 AS valor FROM tabela
    UNION ALL
    SELECT valor2 AS valor FROM tabela
    UNION ALL
    SELECT valor3 AS valor FROM tabela        
) AS resultado
WHERE valor > 0
GROUP BY valor
ORDER BY valor;
```

Veja [rodando](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b9da7c/4).